# how to write if else in the html td . if block and else block both are executing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to show the data in the `td` according to the values getting from the `model`.

According to the device `id` I need to show the device location. If there is no `id` matching I have to show location - "NA".

My actual code is showing the location name as **NA** like **XYZ School NA**.

Expected : **op - K School**

Getting : **K School NA**

**Code**

```
<td>
    @if (@Model.DevEUI == "D1")
    {
        <span>K School</span>;
    }

    @if (@Model.DevEUI == "96")
    {
        <span>BSNL OFFICE</span>;
    }

    else
    {
        <span>NA</span>;
    }
</td>
```

Comment: It's kind of seeking debugging help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the 2nd `@if` to `else if`

```
<td>
  @if (@Model.DevEUI =="D1") 
  {
    <span>K School</span>; 
  } 
  else if (@Model.DevEUI == "96") 
  {
    <span>BSNL OFFICE</span>; 
  } 
  else 
  {
    <span>NA</span>; 
  }
</td>
```

Comment: @krishnamohan - no problem! glad to have helped. please upvote and mark as answer ;)